# Keep setInterval in the background without restarting when going to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I have a `setInterval` functionality in a component which is a HOC. setInterval will run every, say, 3 seconds for 5 times. Now all my child components are wrapped in this HOC as I need to use this setInterval count in the background. It's polling an endpoint and waiting for a response that needs to be displayed by any child component (when response comes back).

What happens is let's say it begins counting up when child 1 component mounts. E.g. the log will look like:

`Round 1...
Round 2...
Round 3...`

Now when I go to another page / component, what I'd like to happen is for the background `setInterval` to continue counting, which it does. However what happens is another setTimer gets initiated like so:

`Round 1...
Round 2...
Round 3...
Round 4... // continuation of count 
Round 1... // cos I shift page, it started another count
Round 5...
Round 2...`

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: at a glance it seems you the interval should be controlled in a component closer to the "root" of your application rather than in an HOC, with data exchange between it and the children through state management or the context API

Comment: The `setInterval` method returns an `id` for each interval being run. You could keep a reference to a running `setInterval` and check for its existence before starting a new one.

Comment: try to use a global variable to manage the initialization of your interval. For example you can use the storage in the device or navigator I think.

Comment: Seems that the callback you are passing through setInterval is loosing it's reference upon re-render, ie changing the component. Try to assign the callback to a reference that is kept during re-render, like the one returned by the userRef() hook.